# chef knife environment from file not recognising older cookbook version

Tags: chef-infra

i am getting this issue when trying to create an environment.

root@pranjal361:/home/user/chef/chef-repo/environments# knife environment from file dev.rb

ERROR: knife encountered an unexpected error

This may be a bug in the 'environment from file' knife command or plugin

Please collect the output of this command with the `-VVV` option before filing a bug report.
Exception: NoMethodError: undefined method `desciption' for #

I had upgraded my cookbook version from 0.1.0 to 0.2.0.

I had provided prod dependency version as 0.2.0 in the environment .rb file and its getting updated.

But for the dev environment created i had given 0.1.0 which i present in the chef server.

[Chef Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frc6Y.png) Not sure where i am doing wrong.

Any ideas on this.

[Cookbook versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ6M0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to cookbook versions, as you can see from the message: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'desciption'`. You misspelled `description`.